# How can I put an image which is in list to another activity?

Tags: android, image, android-intent, android-activity, bundle

I am doing a notepad application There are also pictures that I saved as SQLite database ine byte in the note list. I have shared the picture [image: here]. As you can see from the picture, I want users to be able to view the picture when they want to view the note. For this I created an imageView in the NoteDetail class and I want to put the selected image there. When the users click the note which one is selected, I want that users can see their image in NoteDeteail.class. how can I do that. The solutions I searched from the internet did not offer me a solution.

I have tried this but not worked;

Here is part of my adapter. I can get id, title, and description. All is ok except for image.

```
 final byte[] outImage = note.getImages();
    ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
    final Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
    holder.takenPhoto.setImageBitmap(theImage);

    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "" + notes.get(position).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent noteDetail = new Intent(context, NoteDetail.class);
            noteDetail.putExtra(Common.NOTE_DETAIL_ID, notes.get(position).getNoteID());
            noteDetail.putExtra(Common.NOTE_DETAIL_TITLE, notes.get(position).getTitle());
            noteDetail.putExtra(Common.NOTE_DETAIL_DESCRIPTION, notes.get(position).getDescription());
            noteDetail.putExtra(Common.NOTE_DETAIL_IMAGE,notes.get(position).getImages());
            context.startActivity(noteDetail);
        }
    });
```

Here is my part of NoteDetail.class. Intents are working well except for image of course.

```
 if (getIntent() != null) {
        ID = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getExtras().get(Common.NOTE_DETAIL_ID).toString());
    }
    setDefaultBackroundColor();
    setDefaultTextType();
    setDefaultTextColor();
    taken_title.setText(getIntent().getExtras().get(Common.NOTE_DETAIL_TITLE).toString());
    taken_description.setText(getIntent().getExtras().get(Common.NOTE_DETAIL_DESCRIPTION).toString());
    taken_photo.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Common.NOTE_DETAIL_IMAGE));
```

Comment: Best option is `Retrieve image from DB again on details screen using note-id, which you pass via intent to details screen`

Comment: I know this is the best solution but I wonder that when I need to get image from list to put on to another activity, how can I do that?